Power series of the reciprocal of f defined as a power series
Defined f(x) as a power series: Sum[a_n*x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}] there is a function that calculates the power series of 1/f(x) like InverseSeries for the inverse?

if you do not want to do long division, you can see this power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic

Mathematica can transform series directly: if we have a series
s = Series[f[x], {x, 0, 3}]
(*    a[0] + a[1] x + a[2] x^2 + a[3] x^3 + O[x]^4    *)

then we can calculate the reciprocal (or other functions) of this series directly:
1/s
(*    1/a[0] - (a[1] x)/a[0]^2 + ((a[1]^2/a[0]^2 - a[2]/a[0]) x^2)/a[0] +
      ((-(a[1]^3/a[0]^3) + (2 a[1] a[2])/a[0]^2 - a[3]/a[0]) x^3)/a[0] +
      O[x]^4                                                                 *)

Sqrt[s]
(*    Sqrt[a[0]] + (a[1] x)/(2 Sqrt[a[0]]) + 1/2 Sqrt[a[0]] (-(a[1]^2/(4 a[0]^2)) + a[2]/a[0]) x^2 +
      1/3 Sqrt[a[0]] (-((3 a[1] (-(a[1]^2/(4 a[0]^2)) + a[2]/a[0]))/(4 a[0])) + (3 a[3])/(2 a[0])) x^3 +
      O[x]^4                                                                 *)

etc.

This should be the proper answer. Transformation of a Series is yet another Series. This reminds me the functionality of the Root.

I think it is a trivial question. It works out of the box in abstract case
Series[1/f[x], {x, 0, 3}]

or in concrete case
f[x_] := Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 0, 10}];
Series[1/f[x], {x, 0, 3}] // Normal


Series works on f[x], and you can sub in its series coefficients after expansion of 1/f[x]:
Series[1/f[x], {x, 0, 6}] /. {f[0] -> a[0], 
   Derivative[k_][f][0] :> k! a[k]} // Simplify

(* SeriesData[x, 0, 
 {a[0]^(-1), 
  -(a[1]/a[0]^2), 
  (a[1]^2 - a[0]*a[2])/a[0]^3,
  -((a[1]^3 - 2*a[0]*a[1]*a[2] + a[0]^2*a[3])/a[0]^4),
  (a[1]^4 - 3*a[0]*a[1]^2*a[2] + 2*a[0]^2*a[1]*a[3] + 
     a[0]^2*(a[2]^2 - a[0]*a[4]))/a[0]^5, 
  -((a[1]^5 - 4*a[0]*a[1]^3*a[2] + 3*a[0]^2*a[1]^2*a[3] + 
       a[0]^2*a[1]*(3*a[2]^2 - 2*a[0]*a[4]) + 
             a[0]^3*(-2*a[2]*a[3] + a[0]*a[5]))/a[0]^6),
  (a[1]^6 - 5*a[0]*a[1]^4*a[2] + 4*a[0]^2*a[1]^3*a[3] - 
     3*a[0]^2*a[1]^2*(-2*a[2]^2 + a[0]*a[4]) + 
          2*a[0]^3*a[1]*(-3*a[2]*a[3] + a[0]*a[5]) - 
     a[0]^3*(a[2]^3 - 2*a[0]*a[2]*a[4] + a[0]*(-a[3]^2 + a[0]*a[6])))/
   a[0]^7
  }, 0, 7, 1] *)


If you are satisfied with the result up to some fixed power $x^n$, the following code will do the job. Here, $f(x)=a_0+a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +\cdots$ and $1/f(x)=b_0+b_1 x + b_2 x^2 +\cdots$:
Clear["Global`*"]; 
nmax = 6;
Solve[LogicalExpand[
   Sum[a[n]*x^n,{n,0,nmax}] * Sum[b[n]*x^n,{n,0,nmax}] + O[x]^(nmax+1) == 1], 
   Table[b[n], {n, 0, nmax}]][[1]]


